# Aptana Studio 3 - theme coloring, what is the braces scope for php?

Tags: php, scope, themes, aptana

I have been searching around and cant find an answer... not sure if there is one. I want to change the scope for braces both round and square, and the operators such as the '?' and ':' in the
    ... ? ... : ...;

statement and the => operator in the
    foreach(... as ... => ...)

I have looked at the scope manual for Aptana 3 and they dont seem to cover this for the PHP scope. I was wondering if there is a hack to change these?  I am working in a .php file in an embedded  tag. When you change the embedded source scope it changes all of these things. Is there a way to override for those specific ones I mentioned above?

THanks for anything you can offer me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that all of the tokens you asked for do not have an assigned scope, so they will be colored as default text.

In general, you can place your caret right before (or on) a token, and hit `Ctrl+Shift+p` to see the scope. The past part of the string popup can be used to map that token to a color&font using the Themes preference page.

If you wish to add more tokens support, you will need to ask for it at http://jira.appcelerator.org/